# Substract between columns and print it with AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I have a following input data:

```
AATGCCACGTTGAGAGGCGTTCGCGGAAGGCGCG      44      40.000
AATGCCACTCGGGTCCGAGATGGCGGATCTCCAC      35      37.000
AATGCCAGAGCTGTGGTAGTGTGAAAGCAGCAGT      13      13.000
```

What I want to do is to substract column 3 by column 2
yielding:

```
AATGCCACGTTGAGAGGCGTTCGCGGAAGGCGCG      -4
AATGCCACTCGGGTCCGAGATGGCGGATCTCCAC      2
AATGCCAGAGCTGTGGTAGTGTGAAAGCAGCAGT      0
```

But why this awk doesnt' work:

```
 $ awk '{dif =($3 - $2)}END{print dif}' input.txt
```

Comment: Hey, hang on a minute, that's a copy of my DNA (I recognize the "CGAGATGGCGG" bit on the second line). Where did you get that from?

Comment: Didn't your parents told you are released under an open dna sequence license?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you only print out the difference once, at the end, which means everything but the last row is effectively discarded. (The `END` block runs only once, when the *entire* input has been read and processed) You want this instead:

```
awk 'NF > 0 { print $1 "\t" ($3 - $2) }' input.txt
```

The `NF > 0` prevents awk from printing meaningless 0s for empty lines.